# How is Linear Momentum different from Thrust?

Tags: momentum

I know both theories are different in a complex way, but how them differ from the first ideas of movement? I cant really tell the difference...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with James' explanation of the difference between a "theory" and a "quantity" but just to be more focused on the two keywords in the original question, "linear momentum" and "thrust". They are not the same concepts because they do not have the same units.

The thrust is a force (caused as a reaction to the opposite force). The SI unit of a force is always one newton. However, the linear momentum isn't a force. The force is the *change of the linear momentum per unit time* (using more advanced mathematically defined quantities: the force is the time derivative of the linear momentum). So their units differ by an extra factor of one second.

The thrust may be larger if it is able to achieve a greater change of the linear momentum after the same time; but the thrust may also be larger if it achieves the same change of the linear momentum after a shorter time.

Consequently, the thrust (or any force) and the linear momentum are exactly as different as the distance is different from the speed (or speed is different from the acceleration).

Answer (score 1):

"momentum" and "thrust" are not theories:  They are *quantities* that can be directly or indirectly measured.  We make theories *about* measurable quantities like thrust and momentum.

"Thrust" is another name for the *force* that is exerted on a vehicle by its own propulsion machinery.

*Momentum* is the scalar product of the mass of a body and its velocity.  It's important in theories of motion because it obeys a *conservation law*.

A *theory* is an explanation of some phenomenon or some group of related phenomena.  One could say a *lot* more about what is and what isn't a theory, and one could invite a lot of opinions in the process.  I won't do that here.